# Speed variation of a parachutist

Tags: java

In my exercice, I need to calculate the speed's variation of a parachutist using some mathematical equation given in Exercise. I enter the mass = 80kg and the height = 39000 m

I have to display this message on the sreen :
System.out.printf("%.0f, %.4f, %.4f, %.5f\n",
                    t, height, speed, accel);

Normally, I should have this result :

```
> 133, 1991.2751, 284.9225, -79.22827
> 134, 1742.1436, 216.8788, -57.96464
> 135, 1551.4499, 167.0971, -42.40784
> 136, 1403.5103, 130.6760, -31.02624
```

But unfortunately, this is what I have on my screen :

```
< 133, 1991.2751, 284.9224, -79.22826
< 134, 1742.1436, 216.8788, -57.96463
< 135, 1551.4499, 167.0971, -42.40783
< 136, 1403.5103, 130.6759, -31.02623
```

This is my code here :

```
    final double g = 9.8100;
    float surface = 2;
    int tf = 171;
    double v0 = 00.0;
    double t0 = 00.0;

    for (double t = 0; t < tf; t++) 
    {
        double height= h0;
        double speed= v0;
        double accel = 9.81;

        double s = surface / mass;
        double q = Math.exp(-s * (t - t0));

        speed= (g / s) * (1 - q) + (v0 * q);
        accel = g - (s * vitesse);
        height= h0 - ((g / s) * (t - t0)) - ((v0 - (g / s)) / s) * (1 - q);  

        if ((height<= 2500) && (height> 2300))
        {
            surface = 25;
            System.out.println("## The parachutist open his parachute");
            t0 = 132;
            v0 = 377.927;
            h0 = 2320.2818f;
        }

        // Display on the screen
        System.out.printf("%.0f, %.4f, %.4f, %.5f\n",
                t, height, speed, accel);
    }
```

Can you help me please ?

EDIT : The equations : http://www.casimages.com/img.php?i=131027115003602313.png

Comment: Off topic but can't help myself: "Height 39000 m"??? Poor guy will die of lack of oxygen. Units and orders of magnitude matter...

Comment: You should write down the formula that you are supposed to implement.

Comment: @Floris not to mention that acceleration can only be supposed constant near the surface of earth, since it depends of the distance to the center of Earth.

Comment: I didn't understand your response. This is a simulation of Felix's jump.

Comment: So you are off by one part in 10^7, and you are worried? How do you know what the "right" answer is? Sound to me like typical rounding error due to calculation being done in single precision by one person, and double precision by another. Or different order of operations in evaluation, tiny numerical errors are normal - and insignificant.

Comment: Oh OK - I was about to add "unless you are wearing Felix Baumgartner's space suit"...

Comment: I added the formula in my question

Comment: You have constants that are defined to only three significant digits - thus you must NEVER even quote a result to seven...

Comment: How should I fix that please ?

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you expanded the question to say what you want help with, but it looks like the basic answer is that you are at some point truncating instead of rounding.  If this is for a numerical analysis class, you should think about how you can rearrange the terms to reduce rounding errors. If this is a programming class, you should ask your TA if that error is acceptable. I also notice that `surface` is a `float` where most of the other terms are `double`s, so there may be a little loss of accuracy in that.

Comment: I changed surface to double. But it's the same.

Comment: look at some of the other comments. You're off by a small amount -- the float vs double thing was one suggestion, but the point is that there is a difference in rounding between your version and the one from which you're getting your "good" values. It's almost certainly not significant, since you've only got 3 significant figures on the important constants.

Answer (score 1):

Change your print statement to

```
System.out.printf("%.0f, %.3e, %.3e, %.3e\n", t, height, speed, accel);
```

And if anyone challenges you, say that it would be misleading to quote the results of your calculation to greater precision than the constants used at input (in your case, `g=9.81` limits the precision). We're not even going to talk about the fact (as was mentioned by SJuan76 in one of the comments) that `g` is a function of height, and that, at 39 km above the surface of the earth, it is off by a significant factor. And that there are many other approximations here (his surface is not smooth, the drag is a function of orientation and air density, etc...)

For your reference, since gravitational force goes as `1/r^2`, and r~6300 km, the effective r changes by ~0.6%, so g will change by more than 1%. Which makes even three significant figures generous.

So stop worrying. Rounding errors at the seventh significant figure are a fact of life. But almost never a significant fact...